# Is it possible to listing RDS using C ++? (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-cpp

I would like to listing EC2 and RDS using the C ++ AWS SDK.

The EC2 listing was successful with an example in the AWS document.
However, I can not find an example of an RDS listing.

I need help listing RDS in C ++.
Is there a good example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DescribeDBInstances()` exists in the AWS SDK for C++, according to [this API docs page](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/cpp/api/LATEST/class_aws_1_1_r_d_s_1_1_r_d_s_client.html#abf8886a323e25b8bd03d8e50b18e71f0). In case if you don't find something in the documentation it is always good to check the source code itself. This function's code can be found in the following [GitHub page](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-cpp/blob/master/aws-cpp-sdk-rds/source/model/DescribeDBInstancesRequest.cpp).